# Add an other attribute to link function

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I would like to insert in relation table an other attribute ("`tiers_temps`" in my example) that ids, is it possible with the function "`link()`" or others ?

I use actually this codes, but I must update the filed "`tiers_temps`" :

```
$Examen->link('Users', $listAdd);
```

with the table "user_has_examen" structure :

```
Field       Type    Null  Key Default Extra
user_id     int(11) NO    PRI 0  
examen_id   int(11) NO    PRI 0  
tiers_temps int(11) YES       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a nice way to interact with an intermediate item. But you can act on the relations to retrieve all user, and then, apply your `tiers_temps` value before saving your `Examen`:

```
$Examen->link('Users', $listAdd);

$users = $Examen->Users;
foreach ($users as $user)
{
  $user->tiers_temps = '45';
}
```

Comment: that's the alternative way I found to.
replace $userE by $Examen and that looks to work.
Thanks

Last question, it's more efficient (speed) to use the relation in the foreach or use the array $listAdd that contains users id and loop access unique relation to put the associate tiers_temps ?

Comment: There must be a way to access the related table without querying doctrine to gets data.

Answer (score 0):

There is un error in your proposition. The object $user refers to the table "user" and not "user_has_examen" (not descibe before, that's right) so "tiers_temps" doesn't exist for user.
This solution works but I loop access Doctrine...

```
foreach($user as $userId){
    $UserExam = Doctrine::getTable('UserExamen')->findByDql('user_id = ? AND examen_id = ?', array($userId, $exam))->getFirst();
    if($UserExam->tiers_temps != $users[$userId]){
        $UserExam->tiers_temps = $users[$userId];
        $UserExam->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I find myself in these situations I prefer to give up the table many to many Identifying and move to a structure like this:

- id
- user_id
- examen_id
- tiers_temps

because I find it very inconvenient to manage the value tiers_temps in the structure you used.